# How can I add subtext in list?

Tags: html

http://fiddle.jshell.net/stealthpancakes/jvrqhxdk/5/

I tried to put text in div, but everything after Subtext_1 is displayed in block.

```
Upper_text_1
Subtext_1
Upper_text_2 Upper_text_3


<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><div>Upper_text_1</div><div>Subtext_1</div></li>
        <li>Upper_text_2</li>
        <li>Upper_text_3</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I want something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oxinu.png

Comment: What do you mean by “subtext”?

Comment: If you want something like in the image, you need styling that makes the list horizontal. Show your current styling and explain clearly what needs to be changed or added there.

Comment: I just want to add a text under another text. I want subtext_1 go under Upper_text_1 and keep everything displayed inline like in the image I linked.

Comment: There are millions of ways to put text under other text. Are you just asking how to make a line break? Regarding “inline”, the code posted does not make the items inline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because div is a block level tag, you can try sub instead

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Upper_text_1<br /><span>Subtext_1</span></li>
        <li>Upper_text_2<br /><span>Subtext_2</span></li>
        <li>Upper_text_3<br /><span>Subtext_3</span></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I need Subtext_1 go right under Upper_text_1 not next to it

Comment: Check this new snippet if its ok.

Comment: Yes, text is under another text, but how you keep Upper_text_1, 2 ,3 to be displayed inline?

Comment: ul li {
display: inline-block;
}

Comment: The text says “sub”, but the code uses `span`, and no element is needed. Only the `br` element is relevant here.

Comment: yeah 'br' is enough here, just in case you want to add some style to the Sub_text you can use 'span' for it

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><div>Upper_text_1<span>Subtext_1</span></div></li>
        <li>Upper_text_2</li>
        <li>Upper_text_3</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you need, correct me if am wrong or mistaken.

```
 <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><p>Upper_text_1<br/><sub>Subtext_1</sub></p></li>
            <li><p>Upper_text_2</p></li>
            <li><p>Upper_text_3</p></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Also add the below CSS code:

```
nav ul li{
    margin: 5px;
    display:inline;
}

li p
{
     display:inline;
    float:left;
    margin: 10px;
}


span{
    font-size:0.7em;
}
```

Check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fu66c6b4/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Okie. Edited the answer. See if that helps.

Comment: Now it is under Upper_text_1, but I want keep everything inline.
I just linked an image how it should look like

Comment: Okie. Saw the image now and made changes accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is also correct, but @Debabish_Pothal is simplier.

Answer (score 0):

Div is a block level element. You want an inline element for this case. Try `<em>` tag (emphasis) or the more generic `<span>` tag instead. There is a lot of different semantic elements for different purposes - you should find one that fits your content type and use that.

See this page for a full list:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/HTML5_element_list#Text-level_semantics

Answer (score 0):

```html
     <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>Upper_text_1</li>
             <sub>Subtext_1</sub>
            <li>Upper_text_2</li>
             <sub>Subtext_2</sub>
            <li>Upper_text_3</li>
             <sub>Subtext_3</sub>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```